# Stop content moving when div is set to visible?

Tags: html, css

I have a hidden div which get's displayed when a radio button is clicked, However the paragraph beneath it gets pushed down when I make the div visible, is there any way that I can have the paragraph pushed down even when the div is hidden, so that it doesn't move? Here is my code

HTML

```
<div id="container">Hello</div>
<p>Click the button below to view content</p>
<input type="radio" onclick="displayDiv()">
```

CSS

```
#container {
    display: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Javascript

```
function displayDiv() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: are you sure `document.getElementById('thoughts')` is selecting the right id?

Comment: Oops I copied the wrong code it should be container, but it still moves with the right name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the property `display` by `visibility`; its purpose is to place the div as if it was on the page, but rendering it invisible if you give it a value of "hiden".

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)

CSS:

```
#container {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function displayDiv() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Comment: I have tried this however it still moves the other content down

Comment: Oh, yeah it's working fine there.. have you any idea why it works there and not for me?

Comment: well I can't debug if I can't see your code? Are you sure you have saved your files correctly?

Comment: Ahhh I've got it, it was just me being silly, I had the container div empty and I wanted it to display one of three sentences depending on what button was clicked, and I didn't put any text in the div until I displayed it if that makes sense? But I see now that I can just have one of the sentences in the div at the start, and then when the other buttons are pressed just change the text..

Comment: exactly! Good investigation :)